# Automatically enable Windows 10 touch keyboard & full keyboard with powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, touch, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to write a Powershell script that automatically sets up a Windows 10 platform that uses only a touch screen monitor as it's interface.

I've found this registry key and wrote it into the script:

```
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI"
$Name = "ShowTabletKeyboard"
$value = "1
```

But, we still have to go into Settings>Devices>Typing and manually enable "Show the touch keyboard" and "Add standard keyboard as an option".

I've found ways to set this up for individual applications but not for a system wide configuration.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7 1 to enable

Comment: I'm going to try that now

Comment: if that works add a logon script script from gro with registy values so that you dont have to do it on each computrs

Comment: That was it. Many thanks to @jacksh !

Answer (score 1):

*Partial Answer:* I found that by adding the `TipbandDesiredVisibility` key and setting the value to `1`, it will show the touch keyboard icon in the taskbar. This should be added as a `D_WORD` to:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7
```

Use `1` for on, `0` for off.

*Note:* I haven't found out how to set the keyboard layout.